# 'state' is not defined when using react hooks and backticks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react app using tailwind CSS and am trying to implement an onClick function on a button that will change the color of said button. However, styling is stored in the class name in Tailwind and I am trying to use backticks and the useState hook. I am currently receiving the error of "'state' is not defined"

The code is enclosed below, thanks a lot.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Column(props){
  const [color, setColor] = useState({color:'yellow-200'})

  const onClic=()=>{
    setColor('grey-200')
  }
  return (
    <button className={`w-300 hover:bg-yellow-100 shadow-xl p-6 max-w-xs mr-1.5 ml-4 mt-4 mb-4 bg-${state.color} rounded-xl shadow-md flex items-center space-x-4`} >

        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img class="h-12 w-12" src={props.img} alt={props.name}/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="text-xl font-medium text-black">{props.name}</div>
            <p class="text-gray-500">{props.price}</p>
        </div>
    </button>
  );
};

export default Column;
```

Comment: Guess its a typo, use `color.color` instead of `state.color`.

Comment: I suggest you read the tutorial again, a bit slower and more careful this time. Especially, you look at the [examples given](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), and how they differ from what you are doing, conceptually.

Comment: Your *state* is named `color` and has the shape of `{color:'yellow-200'}`, yet you update it with a simple string later on: `setColor('grey-200')` instead of: `setColor({color:'grey-200'})`. So irregardless of any other error, it will eventually at that point.

Answer (score 2):

With functional components and hooks, you don't need to access `state.color`, you have a state value called `color`, you can use it directly.

```js
<button 
  className={`w-300 hover:bg-yellow-100 shadow-xl p-6 max-w-xs mr-1.5 ml-4 mt-4 mb-4 bg-${color} rounded-xl shadow-md flex items-center space-x-4`} 
>
```

Also, your button needs an `onClick` to handle your state update.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setColor("somecolor");
}

<button 
  className={`w-300 hover:bg-yellow-100 shadow-xl p-6 max-w-xs mr-1.5 ml-4 mt-4 mb-4 bg-${color} rounded-xl shadow-md flex items-center space-x-4`}
  onClick={handleClick}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const [color, setColor] = useState({color:'yellow-200'})
> ```

This creates a variable named `color` in the current scope (and one called `setColor` for updating the state).

It doesn't create a variable named `state` with a `color` property.

Access `color` directly. `state` isn't defined because you didn't define it.